# Mirror list of files

Tags: wget

I've a list of URLs:

```
https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.3.0/angular.min.js
https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-select/1.6.2/js/bootstrap-select.min.css
https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-select/1.6.2/js/bootstrap-select.min.js
https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.24/jquery-ui.min.js
https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js
https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.8.3/moment-with-locales.min.js
https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.0/css/bootstrap.min.css
https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.0/js/bootstrap.min.js
```

And I want to mirror them, with their paths, so I want to end up with those files:

```
/var/www/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.3.0/angular.min.js
/var/www/ajax/libs/bootstrap-select/1.6.2/js/bootstrap-select.min.css
/var/www/ajax/libs/bootstrap-select/1.6.2/js/bootstrap-select.min.js
/var/www/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.24/jquery-ui.min.js
/var/www/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js
/var/www/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.8.3/moment-with-locales.min.js
/var/www/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.0/css/bootstrap.min.css
/var/www/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.0/js/bootstrap.min.js
```

Sure, I can run the list through `sed`, and change the output paths here. But I guess `wget` should be able to do it for me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `-i` switch allows you to specify a list of URLs to download:

```
$ wget -i mylist.txt
```

Additionally, `-P` allows you to specify a path prefix, in your case:

```
$ wget -i mylist.txt -P /var/www/ajax/libs
```

Another solution could be to `cd` to your directory first:

```
$ cd /var/www/ajax/libs && wget -i mylist.txt
```

Finally, the `-x` switch can allow you to *force* the creation of subdirectories:

```
$ wget -i mylist.txt -P /var/www/ajax/libs -x
```

Along with `-nH` (remove hostname directory), you should be able to get the expected result.

```
$ wget -i mylist.txt -P /var/www/ajax/libs -x -nH
```